# How to Upload thousands of Images Wordpress Media Library

Tags: wordpress, image, imagemagick, media

I am currently creating a website with thousands of products. I migrated all the products but the images is an issue because of the long processing time to include them in the media library as I need the different sizes of the images. Anyone had that issue? Here are the solution I was thinking of:

1. Use a plugin such as wp all import and import them -> takes forever -> Not my Favorite option
2. upload the images in my upload folder then run imagemagic to resize and rename. Then run add server plugin to include the images in the media library -> anyone done it? how do I add files in bulk and resize?
3. upload images by hands to the media library -> not even thinking about this one.

An suggestions are welcome

Comment: Using WP may restrict your options but you could upload the full size images and resize them as they are requested and then save them for next time. I had to resize thousands of images once and I setup a php job ( probably not the best or most efficient method ) and ran the code on all images starting with a number then all images starting with abc etc. It took quite a few hours as from memory I was creating 30,000 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forth option is to use WP-CLI Commands and the wp media import command.

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/import/

Also check out this article which covers your second option:

https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/bulk-upload-files-wordpress-media-library-ftp/

Comment: WP-CLI is super fast. Once I downloaded all the files I used WP-CLI and it worked great.